# Как сбросить css-свойство cursor для всех элементов, после значения wait до первоначального значения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

На странице, имеется кнопочка, запускающая длительный процесс, перед выполнением которого я делаю так:

```
$("*").css("cursor", "wait");
```

Чтобы курсор на странице показывал что идет некий процесс.
Далее в конце процесса, я восстанавливаю курсор так:

```
$("*").css("cursor", "auto");
```

Однако, после этих манипуляций, курсор например при наведении на ссылки не становится пальчиком (pointer) как обычно.

Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ не как поправить вашу ситуацию, а как сделать по другому.

Создайте класс в css и просто добавляйте или убирайте его с боди

Добавляем класс к body, если хотим включить

```
$('body').addClass('wait');
```

Если выключить - убираем

```
$('body').removeClass('wait');
```

CSS:

```
.wait *{cursor: wait !important}
```